# Ошибка "файл не найден"

Tags: php

```
<?php

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($username&&$password)
{
$connect = mysql_connect("sql-4.zerver.","bakugan609","s026y8pjtl");
mysql_select_db("bakugan609");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$username'")
$naumrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if ($numrows!=0)
{
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
$dbusername = $row['username'];
$dbpassword = $row['password'];
}

if ($username&&$dbusername&&$password&&$dbpassword)
{

}    
else
echo "Неверный пароль!";

}    
else
    die ("Несуществует такого пользователя!");    
echo $numrows
}

else
{
echo die ("Неверный логин или пароль!");
}
?>
```

Если смотреть в исходном коде, так ничего там не написано!
Пишет, что файл не найден!

Comment: Вопрос аналогичен: Вот у меня есть код, вроде всё правильно ..

.... код ...

Так вот, почему у меня холодильник не включается ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После `$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1")
$naumrows = mysql_num_rows($query)` не забудьте поставить `";"`, а дальше пишите так:

```
if (mysql_num_rows>0){
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
     if ($password == $row['password']){
        //Тут код успешного входа
     } else {
         echo "Неверный пароль";
     }
} else {
  echo "Нет такого пользователя";
}
```

Comment: И не забудьте в запрос добавить LIMIT 1

Answer (score 0):

А почему бы вам не воспользоваться

```
WHERE login='$login' AND password='$password'
```

Чем перебирать всю базу?